# Script that adds new row to sheets in selected AND another Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm working on a Spreadsheet to keep track of team member's project hours. I've created a Spreadsheet per team member for them to fill out weekly, and a project overview Spreadsheet that takes in all data through IMPORTRANGE.

To be able to quickly add a new project I want a macro to insert a new row in the Project overview + the separate Spreadsheets per team member. However I can't figure out how to write the correct code for the separate team member Spreadsheets. What's going wrong here?

If possible I'd also like to make a macro to DELETE a row in the project overview + team member spreadsheets, and one to HIDE a row...

[Project overview](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vg9_m5SQXI6FNBWq762JE2GM6luk9vSpidYN3_aMgak/edit?usp=sharing)

[Team member Kate](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xjR3lx5_KAA9nqiD3YsjZnulQaMyWGPQqgYsjtzQ0xI/edit?usp=sharing)

[Team member David](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q5gtZlqf41of1Zwi8pvZbDx4NN5LcDh5SxfwasLUDMU/edit?usp=sharing)

My current code:

```
function InsertRow() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
    var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();

    // Array holding the names of the sheets to exclude from the execution  
    // I only managed to make it work when I exclude the sheet that I actually want to affect instead of the other way around?
    var exclude = (["PROJECTS"] || 
    SpreadsheetApp.openById("1xjR3lx5_KAA9nqiD3YsjZnulQaMyWGPQqgYsjtzQ0xI").getSheets() ||
    SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Q5gtZlqf41of1Zwi8pvZbDx4NN5LcDh5SxfwasLUDMU").getSheets())

    for(var s in allsheets){
        var sheet = allsheets[s];

        // Stop iteration execution if the condition is meet.
        if(exclude.indexOf(sheet.getName())==-1) continue;

        sheet.insertRowBefore(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is currently your issue?

Comment: Right now the macro adds a row in the project sheet, but not in the 2 separate team member (kate & david) spreadsheets. Guessing I'm doing something wrong in this part...?
(["PROJECTS"] ||    SpreadsheetApp.openById("1xjR3lx5_KAA9nqiD3YsjZnulQaMyWGPQqgYsjtzQ0xI").getSheets() ||
SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Q5gtZlqf41of1Zwi8pvZbDx4NN5LcDh5SxfwasLUDMU").getSheets())

Comment: How are the separate spreadsheets being filled? With the importRange if you create another project on the main sheet, aren't they updated on the others?

Answer (score 3):

As I see it you have a couple of options, which I'll be listing here as A, B, and C. Please note that you might need two different .GS files as you are linking to two sheets

---

### A

> Try code found on google app script documentation

I found the google apps script documentation [for this command found here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid), so you might want to check that for this questions and others , but here is the exact code included

```
// The code below opens a spreadsheet using its ID and logs the name for it.
// Note that the spreadsheet is NOT physically opened on the client side.
// It is opened on the server only (for modification by the script).
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abc1234567");
Logger.log(ss.getName());
```

---

### B

> use open by url instead of open by id

Your issue might be that your current id isn't correct, I have no way of knowing, so here is some alternate code here (link to documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl))

```
// The code below opens a spreadsheet using its id and logs the name for it.
// Note that the spreadsheet is NOT physically opened on the client side.
// It is opened on the server only (for modification by the script).
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(
    'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abc1234567/edit');
Logger.log(ss.getName());
```

---

### C

> Tie the google script to one sheet

This last option doesn't require any code, just an explanation. Instead of trying to link your script to two separate sheets, you might be able to automatically link it to a single google sheet and create two pages in the sheets file that you treat as two different sheets but are one thing. This might not be what you want, but I included it anyways. You link the sheet to the code automatically by:

1 opening your sheet

2 going to "tools"

3 clicking script editor

4 copy and paste your code (except for the "open by id" part)

5 success!

Answer (score 0):

Your `exclude` variable doesn't contain what you think it does. You're using an "or" operator (`||`), which will take the first "truthy" value and skip the rest.

```js
console.log((["PROJECTS"] || 'something else')); // ["PROJECTS"]
```

Moreover, you don't have a good way of telling which spreadsheet belongs to which team member. To solve that problem, you can create an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

```js
const teamSpreadsheetIds = {
  'DAVID': 'ABC',
  'KATE': '123',
};
console.log(teamSpreadsheetIds['DAVID']); // ABC
```

With the `teamSpreadsheetIds` object, you can now go about updating your team member sheets locally as well as their individual spreadsheets. The "PROJECTS" sheet is unique, so there's only one check for it.

```
function InsertRow() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  const row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();

  const teamSpreadsheetIds = {
    'DAVID': '1Q5gtZlqf41of1Zwi8pvZbDx4NN5LcDh5SxfwasLUDMU',
    'KATE': '1xjR3lx5_KAA9nqiD3YsjZnulQaMyWGPQqgYsjtzQ0xI',
  };
  
  for (let sheet of allSheets) {
    const sheetName = sheet.getName();
    const memberSpreadsheetId = teamSpreadsheetIds[sheetName];
    const isSkippable = memberSpreadsheetId === undefined && sheetName !== 'PROJECTS';
    
    if (isSkippable) { continue };
    
    // Insert a row in the local sheet
    sheet.insertRowBefore(row);
    
    // Get the member sheet and insert a row
    if (memberSpreadsheetId) {
      const memberSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(memberSpreadsheetId);
      const memberSheet = memberSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0]; // Assumes the first sheet is the one to modify
      memberSheet.insertRowBefore(row);
    }
  }
}
```